# ForeignKey not being recognised in VS2012 RC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2012

after a lot of help yesterday, I came up against a known error in asp.net4 beta - I upgraded to VS2012 RC Express (4.5), and now VS is reporting two errors in my model, which were ok previously:

"The type or namespace name 'ForeignKeyAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

"The type or namespace name 'ForeignKey' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MvcApplication6.Models
{
    public class tblRental
    {
        [Key()]
            public int rental_id { get; set; }
        public int room_id { get; set; }
        public DateTime check_in { get; set; }
        public DateTime check_out { get; set; }
        public decimal room_cost { get; set; }
        public long customer_ref { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("customer_ref")]
        public virtual tblCustomerBooking Customer { get; set; }

    }

    public class tblCustomerBooking
    {
        [Key()]
        public long customer_id { get; set; }
        public string customer_name { get; set; }
        public string customer_email { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<tblRental> Rentals { get; set; }
    }
```

Does anyone know if the ForeignKey reference has been changed?

Thanks for any help,

Mark

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I just figured out I needed to add:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
```

I didn't need to move it before, so I assume ForeignKey has been moved under the schema namespace.

Hope this helps anyone else,

Thanks, Mark

Comment: by the way you can use Ctrl + .(dot) shortcut for automatic resolving this errors

Comment: Ran into this myself about a week ago... they moved a lot around in the new release

Comment: I'm hitting a reverse problem: Upgraded to RC 2012 and did the above to make my attributes work. I had to then downgrade to .NET 4.0 (Azure does not support .NET 4.5 yet) and now I'm hitting the same ForeignKey and NotMapped attribute not found errors, even though I seem to be referencing the right DLL (System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations). Frustrating.

Comment: Solved: Others might hit this: Do the following if you're forced to downgrade after upgrading. (a) Uninstall EF from Nuget (b) Set the target .NET framework (c) reinstall EF (d) ensure that the .Schema reference is added.

Comment: I spend so much time looking up what libraries what annotations are saved in. Seems like a design problem.