# ASP Entity Framework Fluent API [ForeignKey] annotation error

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I'm trying to set up a one to one relationship and ran into some issue with declaring an attribute as FK.  I already searched and read some of the questions posted here but doesn't address my problem.

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int userId {get;set;}
    [DisplayName("User Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="User name required.")]
    public string username {get;set;}
    [DisplayName("Password")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Password required.")]
    [MinLength(6)]
    public string password {get;set;}
    [DisplayName("Email")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Email required.")]
    public string email {get;set;}

    public virtual List<RoleDetail> roleDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer customer { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int cusomterId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("First Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="First name required.")]
    public string firstname {get;set;}
    [DisplayName("Last Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Last name required.")]
    public string lastname {get;set;}
    [ForeignKey("userId")]
    public int userId {get;set;}
}
```

I'm getting this error when I use the [ForeignKey] annotation.  And I'm using **System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations**.  Also, [Key] works fine.

```
The type or namespace name 'ForeignKeyAttribute' could not be 
found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: this question has nothing to do with the Fluent API....you are using data annotations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem solved after some more Google search. It turns out that the [ForeignKey] annotation is in **System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema**

[ForeignKey not being recognised in VS2012 RC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10893794/foreignkey-not-being-recognised-in-vs2012-rc)

Comment: Good finding! You should not accept my answer because it is plain wrong for EF 5. Better accept your own answer. I've added a remark on top of my answer to make this clear.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

My answer below would be correct for EF < 5.0 but it is wrong for EF >= 5.0. @MooCow's answer is the correct one in this case.

---

The `[KeyAttribute]` and the `[ForeignKeyAttribute]` classes are both in namespace `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` but they are in two different assemblies.

`[KeyAttribute]` is in the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll` assembly which directly belongs to the .NET framework.

However, `[ForeignKeyAttribute]` is in `EntityFramework.dll` assembly that is part of the EntityFramework NuGet package.

In my opinion this can only mean that your project/assembly where your classes are located in doesn't have a reference to `EntityFramework.dll`. If you add this reference it should work.

As a side note: The way you are trying to define a one-to-one relationship won't work. You cannot use a separate foreign key column/property. You must use the primary key itself as a foreign key ([shared primary key association](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/04/14/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations.aspx)), like so:

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("user")]
    public int customerId { get; set; }
    //...
    public User user {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: I double check my NuGet packages and EF 5.0RC is there. I added _System.Data.Entity_ to the class but still giving the same error. I then remove the _System.Data.Entity.dll_ from my references while keeping _EF.dll_ but that didn't solve my problem.

Comment: @MooCow: What is "**EF.dll**"? It should be "**EntityFramework.dll**".

Comment: Sorry my bad. I shorthanded the full name.  Problem solved after some more Google search.